# Traversing hex input that could have 0xff in it in C++

Tags: c++, hex, eof, getchar

I am traversing hex input from stdin in my code, and I noticed that I can't get around my code stopping when a 0xff byte is reached. I know that this happens because loop is :

```
while( (c=getchar()) != EOF)
```

However, I can't leave this out because otherwise getchar is called after the real End-Of-File and it segfaults. How can I traverse the full input correctly?

(sorry I know that there should be a simple answer to this seemingly common task but I tried searching for some time and found nothing)

Comment: while ( (c = getchar() ) ! = EOF )'s body executes if and only if the value you've just read is not EOF. I doubt the error lies in there. More code please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have declared `c` as a char, but [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) returns an `int`. The correct loop construct for C is this:

```
int c;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
  // use c here.
}
```